# Youtube API v3 return 401 when i try to upload video

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I use ServiceAccount uploader for youtube. I use Youtube API v3. 
I have simple console application, that upload video to youtube

```
String serviceAccountEmail = "...";

        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"G:\Youtube\1ffd6ea22be7c41e0852935a0f35438e4beb2e2d-privatekey.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        //, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload
        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
           new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
           {
                                  Scopes = new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload }
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));



        var youtube = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        });

        var video = new Video
        {
            Snippet = new VideoSnippet
            {
                Title = "Video title",
                Description = "Video description",
                Tags = new string[] {"tag1", "tag2"},
                CategoryId = "22"
            },
            Status = new VideoStatus {PrivacyStatus = "public"}
        };

        var fileStream = new FileStream("G:\\1.mp4", FileMode.Open);

        var videosInsertRequest = youtube.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
        videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
        videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

        var uploadThread = new Thread(() => videosInsertRequest.Upload());
        uploadThread.Start();
        uploadThread.Join();

        Console.Read();
```

But this code return error:
**Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).**
Help me, please

This is result by Fiddler:

```
    HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest", error=invalid_token
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 255
Date: Sun, 10 Nov 2013 14:36:29 GMT
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Nov 5 2013 16:15:49 (1383696949)
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.header",
    "reason": "youtubeSignupRequired",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Unauthorized"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Service Accounts don't work with YouTube API. [Here's how to implement OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Service account doesnt work with youtube. Also please ensure that if you are using a gmail ID it must be linked to youtube otherwise you would get 401.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your channel by Youtube App.