# YouTube Data API listChannels request sometimes won't return channel data for users with multiple channels

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) to query YouTube Data API.

First, I get a token from a user with the following scopes:

```
[
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit',
]
```

Then I make `listChannels` request:

```
(new \Google_Service_YouTube($client))->channels->listChannels('snippet', [
    'mine'       => 'true',
    'maxResults' => 1,
]);
```

And most of the times it works like a charm. I get their channel data.

But sometimes it throws an exception with code `401` and the error message:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.header",
    "reason": "youtubeSignupRequired",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Unauthorized"
 }
}
```

It looks like it happens for users who have multiple channels. But I tried adding a new channel to my personal account and choosing that new channel when authorizing access via OAuth. And it worked fine.

It's very confusing as far as why it happens, and the error message doesn't make much sense. Because their tokens are definitely fine, I can renew them or query their Google Plus profiles without problems.

Have anyone encountered that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors), `youtubeSignupRequired` indicates that the user has an unlinked [Google Account](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=27439), which means that the user has a Google Account but does not have a YouTube channel.

> This error is commonly seen if you try to use the OAuth 2.0 Service Account flow. YouTube does not support Service Accounts, and if you attempt to authenticate using a Service Account, you will get this error.
>
> The [YouTube API blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/10/introducing-google-account-support-and.html) introducing Google Account support also discusses the youtubeSignupRequired error in more detail. Although the blog post explains the error for API version 2.1, the meaning of the error is still applicable.

Here are some related posts which might help:

- [Youtube API v3 return 401 when i try to upload video](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25451858/5832311)

  > Service account doesnt work with youtube. Also please ensure that if you are using a gmail ID it must be linked to youtube otherwise you would get 401.
- [Youtube v3 api 401 Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17621982/5832311)

  > The reason "youtubeSignupRequired" usually means the YouTube account has not been set up properly or you have not created your YouTube channel yet. This is a requirement before you can upload videos. It would be great if Google could improve their error message for this case and make it a bit more verbose.

Hope this helps!